# How to save data on a persistent store with rubymotion?

Tags: rubymotion

I tried to find the best way to store data on a local persistant store but I did not find a lot of resources about this.

I found only :

- Motion model

But what is the best gem/way to make a offline app. I mean, I sync with remote one time and after that, my application uses a local storage (cora data, sqlite...) to read data?

Thank you

Comment: what's wrong with core data? are you just looking for resources? http://rubymotion-tutorial.com/7-models/

Comment: CDQ, for sure. http://github.com/infinitered/cdq

Comment: CDQ looks to be right ! I did not find it from google. Thank you! Can you make a right answer to validate it?

Answer (score 1):

I use [MotionModel](https://github.com/sxross/MotionModel) (heck, I *wrote* MotionModel) but I'm biased. It's supposed to be for use-cases where you don't want to set up the Core Data stack. That said, [InfiniteRed](https://github.com/infinitered/cdq%20%27InfiniteRed%27) has done a great job with RMQ so it's likely they did a great job with CDQ, which wraps Core Data.

I suggest you make a play app with each and decide for yourself.

Comment: Hi steve, I don't feel like asking it as an issue on github, but as your answer made me start the use of it, I'm asking you something : I've set it right, models get saved, etc… the db gets larger as new data comes in. But if I close and reopen the app, all get lost as the database was brand-new. Is this a normal behavior ?! I was expecting it to work somehow like a mysql db — you save a record, you obviously can get it later

Comment: Ben, in MotionModel (I hope that's what you're asking about), persistence only happens when you want it to. It's not automatic. Look at https://github.com/sxross/MotionModel#serialization for more information. I wrote a module that can be included that watches for changes and persists the model, but it's not yet ready for prime time.

Comment: Ahah my mind is still only in this rails-mysql way. damn can't think about a use case that would make you use it, but not "persistent-store" anything. Thanks fr the link, i'll check out

Comment: The use case is when you have remote updates and performance tweaking indicates that you should save data only every so often. The philosophy is that most things are tweakable for performance reasons. This gist will show you how to set up a watcher in your model so you can watch it and respond: https://gist.github.com/sxross/7cfa64b330beacad1409. Usage is `@watcher = MyModel.watch{|notification| MyModel.serialize_to_file('my_model.dat')`. Be sure to `MyModel.stop_watching(@watcher)` when you are done if you don't want leaking observers.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the way HipByte suggests in the Locations sample.

Check the [LocationsStore](https://github.com/HipByte/RubyMotionSamples/blob/master/ios/Locations/app/locations_store.rb) class, and how they use CoreData in a very simple way.

Comment: The Location example is *very* simple.  As soon as you want to use multiple models, it gets confusing.  I wrote whole series of blog posts on the topic at http://www.wndx.com/?category=Core+Data, starting with http://www.wndx.com/blog/core-data-basics-in-rubymotion

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [CouchbaseLite](http://www.couchbase.com/mobile#lite) and leverage it's sync capabilities to make the data available offline. I created an [CouchbaseLite RubyMotion Example](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/ToDoLite-Motion) which is a port of a [TodoLite-iOS](http://github.com/couchbaselabs/ToDoLite-iOS) version of the App. I'm currently working on making the integration nicer and more ruby like, but it works as is.